# Download exe file from OneDrive using powershell

Tags: powershell, onedrive

How to download exe file from OneDrive using power shell script

```
# Source file location 
$source = 'https://ericsson-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/personal/yasser_ghanem_ericsson_com/Documents/pW/AnyDesk.exe?download=1' 

# Destination to save the file 
$destination = 'C:\Test\AnyDesk.exe' 

#Download the file 
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $destination 

C:\Test\AnyDesk.exe 
Pause 

Program 'AnyDesk.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
```

Comment: Try the exact same phrase on Google. If you're still having trouble with whatever you come up with regarding your powershell code, then update the question to include your code so we can assist with troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Abraham , i am using this script
# Source file location
$source = 'https://ericsson-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/personal/yasser_ghanem_ericsson_com/Documents/pW/AnyDesk.exe?download=1'
# Destination to save the file
$destination = 'C:\Test\AnyDesk.exe'
#Download the file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $destination
C:\Test\AnyDesk.exe
Pause
Program 'AnyDesk.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Comment: SO rules:  [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [No images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) --- [make an attemp](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: [powershell 3 ways to download](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

Comment: Still getting the the same error "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform –

Comment: It is downloading the webpage and saving it as the file name you suggested.  So the issue is that you aren't getting the exe.  You are getting a .html page.  If you rename it as a .html you'll be able to look at the page.